# Example of a false proof when a Fourier series is not unique?

Tags: analysis, fourier-series

I am attempting to come up with an example to illustrate why one should care that a function has a unique Fourier series expansion.  Inspired by the fact that one can rearrange terms in a conditionally convergent series to obtain any number they want, I'm hoping that if one has a function with a non-unique Fourier series expansion, then one can do something with that series to obtain some kind of false result.  Is anyone aware of such an example? Thank you.

Comment: What  definition of Fourier series do you use? The one I'm familiar with says that the Fourier series is a formal series of certain form, with coefficients defined by a certain formula. Such a thing is unique by definition.

Comment: I'm assuming that $f(x)$ can be written as $f(x)=a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (a_n\cos(nx)+b_n\sin(nx))$.  Now you mentioned formulas for the coefficients $a_0,a_n$ and $b_n$, but as I understand it, you start with $f(x)$ having a Fourier series as above, and deduce the formulas for those $a_0,a_n$ and $b_n$ by doing things like integrating both sides term-by-term.  I'm not assuming $f(x)$ is integrable, or anything else nice about it other than it has a Fourier series.

Comment: In fact, I know that such an example that I desire will require $f(x)$ to be not defined or give up convergence on an infinite set.  So I realize the example and false proof I'm looking for is bound to be quite nasty.

Comment: OK, but what makes a series a Fourier series for $f$? What does "can be written as" mean?

Comment: Suppose a function $f$ is defined on $T \subseteq (0,2\pi)$ and that there are real numbers $a_0,a_n,b_n$ for $n=1,2,\ldots$ such that $f(x)=a_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(a_n\cos(nx)+b_n\sin(nx))$ for all $x\in T$ whenever the RHS converges at $x$. Then the function $f$ has a Fourier expansion.

Comment: So you accept $e^x = \sum e^{n}\cos nx$ as a Fourier series of $e^x$? It converges to $e^x$ whenever the series converges, which is never. If we take this definition, then every function has infinitely many Fourier series, and there is no contradiction to be derived from non-uniqueness.

Comment: So that would just mean that $e^x$ has that Fourier expansion you mentioned above on $\emptyset$, which I think for my purposes would be okay to say.

I perhaps didn't make myself clear when I talked about a contradiction.  I'm hoping that in such a case, you can naively do something to the series that you actually are not justified in doing because the expansion is not unique.  Like in the conditional convergence example I gave above, one naively (and incorrectly) assumes commutativity and then arrives at a contradiction.  I'm hoping one can do something like that...

Comment: But with this definition, there is no reason why one should care about non-uniqueness. Of course, the "Fourier series", as defined above, is not unique. An everywhere divergent trigonometric series is  a "Fourier series" of every function. Who cares? There are no results to be obtained from such a weak concept of a "Fourier series", anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this might be a suitable example. We know that FT of an everlasting sinusoid of frequency $f$ is two impulses of strength ($\pi$) at frequencies $\pm f$. Now in the case of Linear Frequency Modulation, the frequency of a carrier is linearly modulated.

Suppose the modulation is up-chirp, ie, the frequency is linearly increasing, say, from $f_1$ to $f_n$. The FT of this signal would be a series of impulses, each of amplitude ($\pi$), at the frequencies $\pm(f_1, f_2, .....f_n)$.

Now we take another LFM signal, with a down chirp, ie, the frequency is linearly decreasing from $f_n$ to $f_1$. The FT of this function would also be the same as the previous function with up-chirp. Thus just by seeing the FT, we cannot make out whether the frequency was increasing or decreasing.

Hope this throws some light.